# How can i fix this getJSON method()?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an exercise that i have to use getJSON method to display the information from http://headers.jsontest.com/ on a html page!

Below is my code of js. . and i dont know how to fix this . .

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#id-a a').click(function() {
var url = "http://headers.jsontest.com/";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
$('#content').empty();
$.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {
var html = '<div class="entry">';
html += '<div class="language">' + entry['Accept-Language'] + '</div>';
html += '<div class="host">' + entry['Host'] + '</div>';
html += '<div class="usr">'+ entry['User-Agent'] + '</div>';
html += '<div class="accept">'+ entry['Accept'] + '</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';

$('#content').append(html);
});
});
return false;
});

})
```

Help me out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data['Accept-Language']` instead of `entry['Accept-Language']`. And remove the `$.each`, because that will iterate thorugh the keys, not through the objects.

**HTML**

```
<div id="id-a" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #000">
    <a href="#">click me</a>
</div>

<div id="content" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #000; margin-top: 30px;"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id-a a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = "http://headers.jsontest.com/";
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                $('#content').empty();
                var html = '<div class="entry">';
                html += '<div class="language">' + data['Accept-Language'] + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="host">' + data['Host'] + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="usr">' + data['User-Agent'] + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="accept">' + data['Accept'] + '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                //html += '</div>'; //Do not need this, there are no opening tag for this div.
                $('#content').append(html);
            });
            //Do not need this. Use e.preventDefault(); instead.
            //return false;
        });
    })

</script>
```